# Decrypt sound file content in NodeJS from encryption in Java

Tags: java, android, node.js, encryption, cryptography

**Hello guys,**

I'm working on a project that need to encrypt file content in Android and upload it to a server and then decrypt it with NodeJS service.

I have looked over a few projects that based on AES in Java and NodeJS and found something that worked on Java and not on NodeJS.

**Here is the code in Java:**

```
public static String encrypt(String encodeKey, String inputFile) throws Exception {

    byte[] input = getStringFromFile(inputFile).toString().getBytes("utf-8");

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(encodeKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    String data = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("Crypto | Length", String.valueOf(ctLength));
    Log.d("Crypto | Keypass", encodeKey);

    return data;
}
```

**And the code in NodeJS:**

```
var 
  decipher  = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', encryption_key),
  chunks    = [];

  chunks.push( decipher.update( new Buffer(fullBuffer, "base64").toString("binary")) );
  chunks.push( decipher.final('binary') );
  var decrypted = chunks.join("");
```

As you can see, for each of the files i'm generating a new key-hash for salt (it's the same for decrypt and encrypt);

My problem is that when i'm trying to decrypt it i'm getting this error from NodeJS:

> digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the Java [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class correctly. You need to call the [`doFinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal-byte:A-) method. Since you aren't doing piecemeal encryption anyway you can dispense with the pre-sizing of the `ciphertext`, eliminate the call to `update`, and simply call

```
byte [] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input);
```

Comment: replaced by it.